# SQL - How to merge column values to equate out to a new total result

Tags: sql

I am running the following query to output add on orders and cancels so we can manage licenses our company uses more efficiently using an excel sheet with the query return data. So far, everything is working, but I wanted to know or see if there was a way to merge "duplicate" add on names. For example, in the screenshot we can see that we have 85 purchases of Unity Receptionist and 4 purchases of Unity Receptionist $35. These are the same licenses and I want one column with just Unity Receptionist with a total of 89 license count. Same with the Cancel version of Unity Receptionist and Unity Receptionist $35 Cancel

Below is my query that I am running to pull all this data

```
select  sod.add_on_name, sum(sod.add_on_qty) AS ADD_ON_QTY  
from subscriber_order so  
join subscriber_order_detail sod on     
    so.subscriber_order_id=sod.SUBSCRIBER_ORDER_ID  
join corp_acct c on c.subscriber_id=so.subscriber_id  
join PROV_CORP_ACCT_ZONE_XREF z on z.corp_acct_nbr=c.corp_acct_nbr 
where add_on_name like 'Unity%'  
  and add_on_name not like '%Discount%' 
  and order_date >= Sysdate-90
  and add_on_name 
group by  sod.add_on_name
order by case 
when sod.add_on_name like '%Cancel%' then 2
else 1
end;
```

[Query return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cgKq.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use like in group by and case

```
 Select  
 CASE
   WHEN sod.add_on_name LIKE 'Unity Receptionist%' THEN 'Unity Receptionist'
 END AS add_on_name, 
 SUM(sod.add_on_qty) AS ADD_ON_QTY  
 FROM subscriber_order so  
 JOIN subscriber_order_detail sod on so.subscriber_order_id=sod.SUBSCRIBER_ORDER_ID  
 join corp_acct c on c.subscriber_id=so.subscriber_id  
 join PROV_CORP_ACCT_ZONE_XREF z on z.corp_acct_nbr=c.corp_acct_nbr 
 where add_on_name like 'Unity%'  
 and add_on_name not like '%Discount%' 
 and order_date >= Sysdate-90
 and add_on_name 
 GROUP BY 
 CASE
   WHEN sod.add_on_name LIKE 'Unity Receptionist%' THEN 'Unity Receptionist'
 END
 order by case 
 when sod.add_on_name like '%Cancel%' then 2
 else 1
 end;
```

Comment: So I tried inserting that replacing my "group by sod.add_on_name" and putting your group by statement and I am getting the following error

ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 9

Comment: You need to add same in select as well as select and group by fields should match

Comment: Ah i got you. Thanks for that help.

Answer (score 0):

Using

GROUP BY 
CASE
   WHEN add_on_name LIKE 'Unity Receptionist%' THEN 'Unity Receptionist'
 END

resolved my issues.